# How to get "i" in a for loop as a global variable?

Tags: python, scope

I'm writing a calculator script in Python 3 which takes 3 variables from a for loop: A, B, and C. This is for factoring a polynomial.
So here below is the script which takes in A, B, And C:

```
numbers = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for i in numbers:
    try:
        print(i)
        i = int(input())
    except:
        print('Enter a whole number')
```

Then I try to print what they entered for A multiplied by what they entered for B.

but since A, B, and C were created in block scope, it sends me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Is there a way to make A, B, and C global variables even though they are assigned by "i" in the for loop?

Comment: You never define the variables A, B, C

Comment: @knosmos I was hoping to let "i" define A, B, and C as the loop progresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you do it.  You store the input variables in a list, then you pull them from the list.

```
number = []
for name in 'ABC':
    while True:
        try:
            i = int(input(name))
            number.append(i)
            break
        except:
            print('Enter a whole number.')

print( "Sum is", number[0] + number[1] + number[2] )
```

And yes, I know about the "sum" function, but since he didn't tell us what he wants to DO with the three values, this shows how to access them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! For the 3 variables, I was trying to multiply A and C together, and leave B alone.